# Set Outlook to Always Ignore Message Redaction Requests?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I'm not sure what the exact terminology is, but in an Exchange/Outlook corporate environment there is an option for a user to request that a message be redacted after it's been sent.  Is there a way to set my Outlook client (2007) to always ignore those requests so I can keep a local copy of the email anyway?  Does it require that I change to some kind of "offline mode" and always store messages locally?  (Because that latter part is certainly an option if it's available/necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your tracking options (under Advanced Email preferences, which is under email preferences, which is under options) to NOT process receipts on arrival.

When that is turned off, then nothing will happen until you click on the return request (because it's not getting automatically processed). And you can then redirect the return requests to the trash. Or, alternately, you can just click on the original email, and move it to another folder *before* opening the return request, and then nothing will happen (if the original email and the recall email are not in the same folder, the recall always fails).